# Object value is undefined but it's there React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code :

```
export default function ProjectView({filteredProjects,revenueGroups}) {
    const [projects,setProjects] = useState(); 

    useEffect(() => {
        const aap = filteredProjects.map(filteredObject => {
            getProjectFields(filteredObject.projectId).then(res => {
                filteredObject.rekt = res.data[0].id; 
            })
            return filteredObject;
        })
        setProjects(aap);
    },[filteredProjects])
```

And the rendered component :

```
return (
    <div className='main'>
        {projects.map(project => (
            <div className='view-container' key={project._id}>
                {console.log(project)}
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
)
```

This works fine , when i console.log(project) like above it shows the following :

```
{
    projectName: "privaye"
    rekt: "project:1b1126ebb28a2154feaad60b7a7437df"
    __proto__: Object
}
```

when i console.log(projectName) it shows the name, but when i console.log(project.rekt) it's undefined... 
eventhough its there when i console.log(project)

Comment: so where are you consolling project.reckt, i can not see this code. Strange, you are for a long time here but still cant understand that if some line is not working it should be provided that people could see directly where is error without guessing

Comment: i tried console.log(project && project.rekt) returns undefined

Comment: then why you provide this code if it doesnt have a line which is not working properly? It is meaningless

Comment: best wishes, my friend!

Comment: try this  ```filteredObject = {...res.data[0], rekt:res.data[0].id }``` then see if your console works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDITED

I didn't notice the was a promise inside :P

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchThings()
},[filteredProjects])

const fetchThings = async () => {
  const promArr = filteredProjects.map(filteredObject => {
    return getProjectFields(filteredProject.project.id)
  })
  const filteredObjects = await Promise.all(promArr)
  const projectsMod = filteredObjects.map(fo => ({
    ...fo,
    rekt: fo.data[0].id,
  }))
}
```

Maybe an approach like this will help you with the asyncronous problem

---

console.log isn't rendering anything so maybe React doesn't try to refresh this part of the DOM when projects state is updated.

You can stringify the object to check the content of the variable inside the return

```
return (
    <div className='main'>
        {projects.map(project => (
            <div className='view-container' key={project._id}>
                <span>{ JSON.stringify(project) }</span>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Returns the object but the rekt value is nowhere to be seen , somehow

Answer (score 0):

You are running promise, after this promise will return value you set `rekt`, but promise will work god knows when, and most probably you check value before this promise resolved.

```
getProjectFields(filteredObject.projectId).then(res => {
  // THIS CODE CAN RUN AFTER RENDERING
  filteredObject.rekt = res.data[0].id; 
})
```

so first you wait till promises will complete and only then set new state

```
const ourPreciousPromises = filteredProjects.map(filteredObject => 
  getProjectFields(filteredObject.projectId).then(res => {
    filteredObject.rekt = res.data[0].id; 
    return {...filteredObject}
  })
})

Promise.all(ourPreciousPromises).then(newObjects => 
  setProjects(newObjects)
)
```

Comment: that is the reason i was asking you where exactly you console, because it is important